# How to modify collection on multi-instance in activiti

Tags: collections, activiti

We are creating POC for a project where we will have 4 stages of approval. Let's say the 4 stages are

1. Accountant
2. Manager
3. Owner
4. Delivery Head

A process has started and right now the user task i.e. approval is at the Accountant level. The multi-instance will loop in a collection returned from Java Service class. While the loop is running for that particular set of users, I want to push a new user in it. I'm able to add more users in the collections of manager, owner and Delivery Head because the approval stage is on Accountant Level and the collection call for those approvers is not performed yet.

My Process XML:

```xml
<startEvent id="startEvent1"></startEvent>
    <userTask id="accountantApproval" name="Accountant Approval" activiti:assignee="${accountant}">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="accountantApprovalValue" name="Accountant Approval Value" type="enum" required="true"></activiti:formProperty>
        <modeler:initiator-can-complete xmlns:modeler="http://activiti.com/modeler"><![CDATA[false]]></modeler:initiator-can-complete>
      </extensionElements>
      <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="true" activiti:collection="${myService.fetchEmployeesByRole('Accountant')}" activiti:elementVariable="accountant">
        <completionCondition>${status != 'Submit'}</completionCondition>
      </multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
    </userTask>
    <userTask id="managerApproval" name="Manager Approval" activiti:assignee="${manager}">
      <extensionElements>
        <modeler:initiator-can-complete xmlns:modeler="http://activiti.com/modeler"><![CDATA[false]]></modeler:initiator-can-complete>
      </extensionElements>
      <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="true" activiti:collection="${myService.fetchEmployeesByRole('Manager')}" activiti:elementVariable="manager">
        <completionCondition>${status != 'Submit'}</completionCondition>
      </multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
    </userTask>
    <exclusiveGateway id="accountantEXOR" name="Accountant EXOR"></exclusiveGateway>
    <serviceTask id="accountantRejectService" name="Accountant Reject Service" activiti:class="com.example.demo.RejectService"></serviceTask>
    <exclusiveGateway id="managerEXOR" name="Manager EXOR"></exclusiveGateway>
    <serviceTask id="managerRejectService" name="Manager Reject Service" activiti:class="com.example.demo.RejectService"></serviceTask>
    <endEvent id="endProcess" name="End Process">
      <terminateEventDefinition></terminateEventDefinition>
    </endEvent>
    <userTask id="OwnerApproval" name="Owner Approval" activiti:assignee="${accountant}">
      <extensionElements>
        <activiti:formProperty id="sid-52D1F400-4813-4B2F-856D-61FE4C41C6FEValue" name="Accountant Approval Value" type="enum" required="true"></activiti:formProperty>
        <modeler:initiator-can-complete xmlns:modeler="http://activiti.com/modeler"><![CDATA[false]]></modeler:initiator-can-complete>
      </extensionElements>
      <multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics isSequential="false" activiti:collection="${myService.fetchEmployeesByRole('Owner')}" activiti:elementVariable="owner">
        <completionCondition>${status == 'Submit'}</completionCondition>
      </multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics>
    </userTask>
```

Now, Suppose if a process has started and it is at the Accountant Level. The multi-instance will fetch the employees from the service class and push it in the collection and it will start looping through it.
Let's say it fetches 2 employees David & Sam.
David approves the task and it moves on to the next approval i.e. Sam.
Sam wants to add another accountant in the loop.

Is there a way to add new users in the current running loop collection i.e. of Accountant collection? If yes, Please suggest a way, preferably using Java.

If we can not add a user in the collection, is there a way we can create a new user task and assign it to the ongoing process? So once the accountant loop is finished, before it moves on to the next approval stage, it should finish the newly created user task.

Comment: Did you find a solution here ? I also found this answer that seems to answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64154874/how-to-update-multiinstance-user-task-to-add-delete-tasks. But I am in the same situation and curious what worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

you will need to elaborate your question more for us to he able to help you. Can you provide a process diagram image or something to clarify how does your process look like?
If you want to add more users you can use Groups for each group of people that you have there.. so instead of having Accountant as a user you can use a group and add dynamically more people to that group.

When you use multi instance nodes, all the instances are created when the execution arrive to the BPMN element and at that point the content of the collection is used, once they are created you cannot change that. What you can do is to loop back to the BPMN element and create the instances again, but that will push you to make sure that you clean up the previous tasks.

If you provide more details we can probably help you with a more detailed answer.

Hope this helps .

Comment: Hi. I have added my process XML and have elaborated my question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a boundary signal event on your multi-instance use task/sub-process, which will cancel all the currently running tasks and create new tasks for the updated collection.

below diagram might help

[image]

**Note**: you will have to call the signal (from your code) after you have updated your collection with `runtimeService.signalEventReceived("yourSignalId", "yourProcessInstanceID");`

Comment: Can someone explain this a bit more? how will this close existing task and start new ones?  Also what does this line mean? `You can use a boundary signal event on your multi-instance use task/sub-process`