# How to update MultiInstance User Task to add/delete Tasks?

Tags: camunda

We have a business scenario where we would like to have the ability to INCREASE or DELETE tasks within a multi-instance context.
I’ve managed to successfully create a mutli-instance User task based on a collection `workPartnerList`

If a Process is working on a multi instance stage of the workflow - how can I increase or decrease the multi instance state based on the count/values of `workPartnerList` which can increase or decrease based on updates from the API call. (we need to do this prior to the overall task completion)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you are referring to a parallel multi-instance task.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/bpmn20/tasks/task-markers/

> Another way to define the number of instances is to specify the name
> of a process variable which is a collection using the loopDataInputRef
> child element. For each item in the collection, an instance will be
> created

The creation of the instances happens at the point in time when the execution reaches the parallel multi-instance activity. The number of instances created is determined by the size of the collection at this specific point in time. (A BPMN2 process engine will not automatically keep the task instances in sync with the collection.)

To "delete" task instance you can complete or cancel them (e.g. via an attached boundary event) or us the completion condition.

> A multi-instance activity ends when all instances are finished.
> However, it is possible to specify an expression that is evaluated
> every time one instance ends. When this expression evaluates to true,
> all remaining instances are destroyed and the multi-instance activity
> ends, continuing the process. Such an expression must be defined in
> the completionCondition child element.

To add additional task instances to a running process instance dynamically you can use for instance event sub processes or attach a boundary event to the task.

https://docs.camunda.org/manual/7.13/reference/bpmn20/events/message-events/#message-boundary-event

> Boundary events are catching events that are attached to an activity.
> This means that while the activity is running, the message boundary
> event is listening for named message. When this is caught, two things
> might happen, depending on the configuration of the boundary event:
>
> Interrupting boundary event: The activity is interrupted and the sequence flow going out of the event is followed.
>
> Non-interrupting boundary event: One token stays in the activity and an additional token is created which follows the sequence flow
> going out of the event.

[image]

If you are willing to approach this on API level then the [TaskService](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.14/org/camunda/bpm/engine/TaskService.html) allows you to create a [new task](https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.14/org/camunda/bpm/engine/TaskService.html#newTask-java.lang.String-) (with a user defined task id).
Example:
https://github.com/rob2universe/cam-multi-instance/blob/25f524be6a112deb1b4ae3bb4f28a35422e428e0/src/test/java/org/camunda/bpm/example/ProcessJUnitTest.java#L79

The migration API would even allow you to add additional instances to the already created set of task instances - see: https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/user-guide/process-engine/process-instance-modification/#modify-multi-instance-activity-instances

Comment: yes its a Parallel Multi Instance. Could you explain this a bit more? I'm sort of new to Camunda!  My multi-instance was created initially say by 3 items in the workPartnerList. Its  now grown to 4 so I need to add one more to the existing tasks. `To add additional task instances to a running process instance dynamically you can use for instance event sub processes or attach a boundary event to the task.`

Comment: Please see additions to answer

Comment: thanks @rob2universe.  This looks like we're starting an independant task OUTSIDE of the original multi-instance task - is that correct?

Comment: Yes. Is that an issue? As mentioned, the task instances created by parallel the multi instance task are determined once when the task is reached / created.

Comment: Also added links to the API options to create and delete tasks to answer.

Comment: yeah ideally i wanted to modify the multi-instance task itself

Comment: Well, it is what it is. What i s the motivation?

Comment: just thought it would be cleaner. but thats moot since it looks like we CANT change the cardinality once created. I see the non-interrputing start event you created - - how can i send a message to trigger this?

Comment: See https://docs.camunda.org/manual/latest/reference/rest/message/post-message/ and https://docs.camunda.org/javadoc/camunda-bpm-platform/7.14/ Would appreciate answer acceptance and up-vote.

Comment: @DorianMcAllister regarding "yeah ideally i wanted to modify the multi-instance task itself" - what I understand is that if you are going with TaskService or with Migration API, then you actually modifying the multi-instance task itself. Isn't this so ?